# how to display popup keys on android virtual keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

I am newbie to android application development. I am currently developing a virtual keyboard with unicode characters. As the number of characters are too many to be displayed on the keyboard, some of them are hidden and only showup when the user preses a similar key. For example, in my cellphone, when I press A, the characters "A", "B", "C" will be displayed as popup keys to let me choose one of them. I just want to implement virtual keyboard similar to my cellphone's keyboard. I know how implement virtual keyboard using the KeyboardView and Keyboard classes, and keyboard xml resource.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to display popup keys?

Answer (score 0):

There are many sample you can use it to help you, Look at this and pick one to use it.

[githup project](https://github.com/g1011999/Gingerbread-Keyboard/)

[Good Blog Documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html)

[tutorial Blog](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.com/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html)

[Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html)

[Custom Keyboard](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for-android-devices/)

Comment: Thanx Omarj, specially the third one "tutorial Blog" was helpful for me as get full control over the buttons pressed. I used a spinner to display the remaining characters of my keyboard. The spinner will popup when the user presses a given key.